# converting varchar to datetime in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, varchar

currently in my DB i have

```
20181015 151706 ---------- varchar(15)
2018-10-15 15:17:06 000--- Datetime
```

how do i convert this from varchar to datetime ?

i have tried using this command below

```
SELECT CONVERT(Datetime,CREATE_TIME , 120) from TABLE
```

but im getting error

"The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

```
SELECT CONVERT(Datetime,CREATE_TIME , 120) from TABLE
```

Comment: Will it work if the date was something like 20181010 151706? If that works, it's because of the date format (YYYYMMDD vs YYYYDDMM).

Comment: What's your dbms? why did you save varchar as datetime value?

Comment: this is sql server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error caused by your special `20181015 151706` `varchar` DateTime value,

you can try to use `substring` function make the DateTime format string value then do `convert`.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,CONCAT(substring(col, 1, 4),'-',substring(col, 5, 2),'-',substring(col, 7, 2),' ',substring(col, 9, 2),':',substring(col, 11, 2),':',substring(col, 13, 2)))
FROM (
   select REPLACE('20181015 151706',' ','') col
) t1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=324402b4085a29eb7f15b536b6021384)

Answer (score 0):

There's a little issue with your date string. It works when `20181015 151706` is changed to just the date part `20181015`.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, col)
FROM (
   select '20181015' col
) t1
```